# Finding the minimum integer satisfying a predicate

Tags: search, j

Is there a good way of finding the smallest integer (starting zero) that satisfies a given predicate in J ?

Answer (score 2):

This is what [infinite power with a right verb](http://jsoftware.com/help/jforc/loopless_code_iv_irregular_o.htm#_Toc191734390) is for (`^:v^:_`). For example, find the first integer divisible by 7.

```
check =: 0 ~: 7 | ]   NB. check if y is not a multiple of 7
(>:^:check)^:_ ] 1    NB. increment y (1) while check is true
7
```

A second point is that if you are searching *in an array*, you can use the [special code](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/special.htm) `f i. 1:` (first place where `x f y`). See: http://www.jsoftware.com/help/release/edot504.htm

Answer (score 0):

Eelvex's answer may be what you are looking for, but one way to read your question is what is the minimum integer greater than 0 in a list.  These functions return index of first conditional minimum.

```
 (i. <./)  _"_^:(<&0)("0) _3 _1 3 4 2
```

4

```
 minatleast =: (i. <./)@]@:(_"_^:>("0))
0 minatleast _3 _1 3 4 2
```

4

```
 3 minatleast _3 _1 3 4 2
```

2